# Pentaho : Text file output : Remove CR&LF from last line of the file generated

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

```
Pentaho - 
Design  : Text file output
Requirement :

- Read values from DB and create a csv file.
- I want to remove the CR & LF from the last line in the generated file.
```

This empty last line is causing problem while file parsing so I want to get rid of it.

Sample example here :

[image]

Test.ktr :
https://ufile.io/ug06w
This produces output.csv in which last line contains CRLF (contains 3 lines - blank line at the end of file)

input.csv
https://ufile.io/lj0tj
(To simulate values coming from database, contains 2 lines)

Comment: Can you provide a 2 line example.

Comment: Done. Added above, please check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could solve this using **Shell Script** component. After generating file I added a post process step to remove the empty line at the end of the file.

There could be other solutions but this fulfilled my requirement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put some logic between the Table input and CSV output, for example the `Filter step` which can remove empty lines.

[image]

I cannot tell you more, unless you tell me more about your specific case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please see the example I provided above and help me solve the issue.